# В каком файле AndroidStuido хранится лог Android Debugger->Вкладка Consol?

Tags: android-studio, консоль, отладка

В каком файле AndroidStuido хранится лог Android Debugger->Вкладка Console?
Хочу читать ошибки и логи приложения извне каким-нибудь внешним текстовым редактором. Есть такая возможность?

Comment: `adb logcat > log.txt`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только я не понял что нужно сделать?

Comment: выполнить эту команду в консоли.